# Is it possible to transform a pivot table into an ordinary table?

Tags: python, excel

So basically, I was wondering if it's possible to transform the table from:

[image: this]

into

[image]

using excel? The table I presented are constructed manually but I also have a data which consist of 2500x26 cells which is not possible at all for manual constructing. If not, is it possible if it's done by python? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to it using `pandas`, with [`.unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) which does exactly this.

something similar to this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("in_file.xlsx")
df = df.unstack()
df.to_excel("out_file.xlsx")
```